# How do I beat Zone ?-4 of 1P Extra Pack 2 in Bust-A-Move Plus?

Tags: bust-a-move-plus

I was playing Bust-A-Move Plus! (aka: Puzzle Bobble Wii) and I came across this level today, and have no idea how to beat it.  It's from 1P Extra Pack 2, Zone ?-4. I've searched everywhere and can't find anything about this level anywhere on the internet

It contains nothing but Star Bubbles and Support Blocks. About every 2 shots, the screen drops one level, and if any of the bubbles or blocks gets past the line, I lose (as expected).  I know I have to start by removing the bottom most Support Blocks but I always come up one move short of doing that.

Here is what I'm doing to free the two lower sets of Support Blocks:

I take 2 shots for the 3 Star Bubbles on the right, 2 for the 3 Star Bubbles on the left, 3 to disconnect them both from the middle, and 2 more (one for each side) to free up the last Star Bubble on the top of each set of Support Blocks. However before I can shoot the last Star Bubble to disconnect final Star Bubble on the remaining side the level moves down and I lose.

Anyone have any ideas?  Thanks.

[image: A picture of the level]